# Unity C# variable not assigned

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas, text

It's actually kinda funny. I got two text UIs in my project. Both in canvas. They are called text1 and text 2. I did the same thing to both in the script. text1 is fine but text 2 doesn't seem to be assigned as unity error says: 'UnassignedReferenceExeption: The variable text2 of larrytalk has not been assigned.'

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class larrytalk : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject FPS;
[SerializeField] public GameObject text1;
[SerializeField] public GameObject text2;
[SerializeField] private GameObject Larry;
[SerializeField] private GameObject Turm;
[SerializeField] private GameObject sockel;
CharacterController cc;

bool hold;



// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    GameObject Larry = GameObject.Find("larry1");
    GameObject Text1 = GameObject.Find("Text1");
    GameObject Text2 = GameObject.Find("Text2");
    GameObject charactercontroller = GameObject.Find("FPSController");
    GameObject Turm = GameObject.Find("mpp u3");
    GameObject sockel = GameObject.Find("beton");

    text1.SetActive(false);
    text2.SetActive(false);


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Input.GetMouseButton(0) && cc.height < 20 && Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, this.transform.position) < 10)
    {
            text1.SetActive(true);
    }

   if( Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, this.transform.position) > 20)
    {
        text1.SetActive(false);
    }
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Input.GetMouseButton(0) && cc.height < 20 && Vector3.Distance(sockel.transform.position, Turm.transform.position) <10)
    {
        text2.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        text2.SetActive(false);
    }
}
}
```

everything related to text1 works fine. Why doesnt text2 as well?

Comment: its telling you that at the time that start function happened, "Text2" was not to be found.  That doesnt mean that the next thing it did was make one.. but at that time it was not there.

Comment: Are you serializing or deserializing?  I would think the error is occurring on deserialize.  When you get error during deserialize it means the class definition when you serialized changed.  The deserialize method must use the same object that was used to serialize.  If you added properties after you serialized you will get errors.

Comment: I would agree if there would be something diffrent between the way i used text1 and text2. Thats what i dont get.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: fixed it about an hour ago and forgot the exact error but it was simply my noob status with unity and something basic

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you declare new variables in your start method and you do NOT assign the ones you declared at the top of your script.
Change

```
GameObject Text2 = GameObject.Find("Text2");
```

To

```
text2 = GameObject.Find("Text2");
```

And do the same for the other fields.

As for why text1 doesn't throw an error, it is probably assigned in the inspector and text2 isnt.